# Using the Like Operator Along with Wildcard in MS Access VBA

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am trying to duplicate this SQL Query in MS Access VBA.  I keep running into syntax errors.  I am not sure where to use single quotes or double quotes or what have you.  I'm driving myself up a wall.  Could someone please duplicate this SQL code for me in VBA. I am using the docmd.RunSQL(string) command.  Thank you!

```
Delete [Carrier File Report].[Project Tasks Name] FROM [Carrier File Report] WHERE ((([Carrier File Report].[Project Tasks Name]) Like "'" * Test * "'"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you intend?

```
WHERE [Carrier File Report].[Project Tasks Name] Like "*Test*"
```

Comment: The double quotes will cause an error in RunSQL. You have to either use single quotes or double-double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

If you are really looking for anything matching Test then

```
"...    Like '*Test*'"
```

If `Test` is a string variable you are trying to use then

```
 "...   Like '*" & Test & "*'"
```